# PHPUnit: Test a class who calls another class

Tags: composer-php, phpunit

I have a class with a constructor like this:

```
class ClassA {

       public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->enrollment= new classB( $this );

    }
}
```

And the classB like:

```
class classB{

    public function __construct( $parent ) {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
}
```

The class A have a function that calls a function of class B and that function is what I want to test, the call flow of the functions is:

```
class ClassA {

       public function register_enrollment_custom_post_type(){
        $this->enrollment->classB_function();
    }
}
```

```
class classB{

    public function classB_function(){
        //anything
    }
}
```

How can you think that I can test with PHPUnit & composer that classB_function()?

I have tried create an instance using new ClassA() of classA but it gives me an error: Class "classB" not found. The problem is when I run the test creating the classA with "new ClassA()" always give me the error "classB not found" referring to the $this->enrollment= new ClassB( $this ) line in classA constructor

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the current approach? How is your problem related to Composer?

Comment: Idk if the problem is directly related to composer but the problem is when I run the test creating the classA with "new ClassA()" always give me the error "classB not found" referring to the $this->enrollment= new ClassB( $this ) line in classA constructor

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share in which files your classes are stored. Keep in mind that `classB` (as in the class defintiions) and `ClassB` (as in the constructor) refer to two different classes

Comment: Did it, I referred to the problem at the end and fixed ClassB typo.